# Como efetuar JOIN onde o identificador não pôde ser associado

Tags: sql-server, join

Possuo pronta a seguinte query num antigo sistema:

```
SELECT regional, r.cod_gerente AS cod_gerente, 
    u2.username AS nome_gerente, 
    s.COD_REPRESENTANTE AS cod_representante, 
    u1.username AS nome_representante, 
    SUM(s.jan_valor) AS valor_total_seca, 0 as valor_total_liquida 
    FROM USUARIOS U1, USUARIOS U2, USUARIOS_USUARIOS R, cubo s 

    WHERE s.COD_GRUPO IN (1) 
    AND s.ANO = year(getdate()) 
    AND U1.COD_SISTEMA > 0 
    AND R.COD_REPRESENTANTE = U1.COD_SISTEMA 
    AND U2.COD = R.COD_GERENTE 
    AND U2.SUB_GERENTE = 1 
    AND (s.cod_representante = U1.COD_SISTEMA) 
    AND (PATINDEX('%' + CAST(s.cod_grupo AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%', U2.GRUPOS) > 0 
        AND PATINDEX('%' + ( (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(cod_canal AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                                FROM clientes 
                                WHERE cod_cliente = s.cod_cliente)) + '%', u2.canais) > 0) 
    GROUP BY regional, r.cod_gerente, u2.username, s.COD_REPRESENTANTE, u1.username, u2.grupos
```

Eu preciso agora selecionar a `matricula_usuario` na tabela `tab_comissoes` conforme a coluna `cod_usuario` da tabela `usuarios`. Efetuei um LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT tab.matricula_usuario as tabCodigo , regional, r.cod_gerente AS cod_gerente, 
    u2.username AS nome_gerente, 
    s.COD_REPRESENTANTE AS cod_representante, 
    u1.username AS nome_representante, 
    SUM(s.jan_valor) AS valor_total_seca, 0 as valor_total_liquida 
    FROM USUARIOS U1, USUARIOS U2, USUARIOS_USUARIOS R, cubo s 
    LEFT JOIN tab_comissoes as tab ON  tab.cod_usuario = U2.cod 

    WHERE s.COD_GRUPO IN (1) 
    AND s.ANO = year(getdate()) 
    AND U1.COD_SISTEMA > 0 
    AND R.COD_REPRESENTANTE = U1.COD_SISTEMA 
    AND U2.COD = R.COD_GERENTE 
    AND U2.SUB_GERENTE = 1 
    AND (s.cod_representante = U1.COD_SISTEMA) 
    AND (PATINDEX('%' + CAST(s.cod_grupo AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%', U2.GRUPOS) > 0 
        AND PATINDEX('%' + ( (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(cod_canal AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                                FROM clientes 
                                WHERE cod_cliente = s.cod_cliente)) + '%', u2.canais) > 0) 
    GROUP BY regional, r.cod_gerente, u2.username, s.COD_REPRESENTANTE, u1.username, u2.grupos
```

Porém recebo o erro:

> [Error Code: 4104, SQL State: S1000]  O identificador de várias partes
>   "U2.cod" não pôde ser associado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não misture sintaxe ANSI com sintaxe simplificada. O SQL Server se perde.

Use da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT tab.matricula_usuario as tabCodigo , regional, r.cod_gerente AS cod_gerente, 
    u2.username AS nome_gerente, 
    s.COD_REPRESENTANTE AS cod_representante, 
    u1.username AS nome_representante, 
    SUM(s.jan_valor) AS valor_total_seca, 0 as valor_total_liquida 
    FROM USUARIOS U1
    INNER JOIN USUARIOS_USUARIOS R ON (R.COD_REPRESENTANTE = U1.COD_SISTEMA)
    INNER JOIN USUARIOS U2 ON (U2.COD = R.COD_GERENTE)
    INNER JOIN cubo s ON (s.cod_representante = U1.COD_SISTEMA)
    LEFT JOIN tab_comissoes as tab ON tab.cod_usuario = U2.cod 

    WHERE s.COD_GRUPO IN (1) 
    AND s.ANO = year(getdate()) 
    AND U1.COD_SISTEMA > 0 
    AND U2.SUB_GERENTE = 1 
    AND (PATINDEX('%' + CAST(s.cod_grupo AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '%', U2.GRUPOS) > 0 
        AND PATINDEX('%' + ( (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(cod_canal AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                                FROM clientes 
                                WHERE cod_cliente = s.cod_cliente)) + '%', u2.canais) > 0) 
    GROUP BY tab.matricula_usuario, regional, r.cod_gerente, u2.username, s.COD_REPRESENTANTE, u1.username, u2.grupos
```

Comment: Cigano, ocorreu o erro ` [Error Code: 8120, SQL State: S1000]  A coluna 'tab_comissoes.matricula_usuario' é inválida na lista de seleção porque não está contida em uma função de agregação nem na cláusula GROUP BY.` . Então adicionei ao GROUP BY o campo `tab.matricula_usuario`. Há outra maneira ou isso é o suficiente?

Comment: Se rodou depois da correção, fique à vontade para editar minha resposta.